# System freezes when I download and install the bcmwl-kernel-source package

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I'm trying to install drivers for my Archer T9E wifi adapter, but my system always freezes whether I do the install of `bcmwl-kernel-source` through GUI or terminal.

How can I fix this?

out put of `sudo apt-get install -f bcmwl-kernel-source`

[image]

Here is the output of my `lshw`

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw
[sudo] password for user: 
 ubuntu                    
description: Desktop Computer
product: To be filled by O.E.M. (To be filled by O.E.M.)
vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
version: To be filled by O.E.M.
serial: To be filled by O.E.M.
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To be filled by O.E.M. sku=To be filled by O.E.M. uuid=40028D03-5C04-FF05-7306-BD0700080009
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: GA-990FX-GAMING
   vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   version: x.x
   serial: To be filled by O.E.M.
   slot: To be filled by O.E.M.
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
      physical id: 0
      version: F2
      date: 04/06/2016
      size: 64KiB
      capacity: 4032KiB
      capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
      physical id: 4
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: CPU 1
      size: 1400MHz
      capacity: 3500MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 200MHz
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt lwp fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate vmmcall bmi1 arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold cpufreq
      configuration: cores=6 enabledcores=6 threads=6
    *-cache:0
         description: L1 cache
         physical id: 5
         slot: L1-Cache
         size: 288KiB
         capacity: 288KiB
         clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
         capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
         configuration: level=1
    *-cache:1
         description: L2 cache
         physical id: 6
         slot: L2-Cache
         size: 6MiB
         capacity: 6MiB
         clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
         capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
         configuration: level=2
    *-cache:2
         description: L3 cache
         physical id: 7
         slot: L3-Cache
         size: 8MiB
         capacity: 8MiB
         clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
         capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
         configuration: level=3
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 2c
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 8GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
         product: KHX1600C10D3/
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 0
         serial: 791CB90A
         slot: Node0_Dimm0
         size: 8GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm1_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm1_Manufacturer
         physical id: 1
         serial: Dimm1_SerNum
         slot: Node0_Dimm1
    *-bank:2
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm2_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm2_Manufacturer
         physical id: 2
         serial: Dimm2_SerNum
         slot: Node0_Dimm2
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
         product: Dimm3_PartNum
         vendor: Dimm3_Manufacturer
         physical id: 3
         serial: Dimm3_SerNum
         slot: Node0_Dimm3
 *-pci:0
      description: Host bridge
      product: RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B)
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:25 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fea00000-feafffff ioport:c0000000(size=270532608)
       *-display UNCLAIMED
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            version: c7
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
            resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea3ffff memory:fea40000-fea5ffff
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
            resources: irq:38 memory:fea60000-fea63fff
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port H)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 9
         bus info: pci@0000:00:09.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:24 memory:fe900000-fe9fffff
       *-usb
            description: USB controller
            product: ASMedia Technology Inc.
            vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: msi msix pm pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
            resources: irq:27 memory:fe900000-fe907fff
          *-usbhost:0
               product: xHCI Host Controller
               vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic xhci-hcd
               physical id: 0
               bus info: usb@9
               logical name: usb9
               version: 4.04
               capabilities: usb-3.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=5000Mbit/s
          *-usbhost:1
               product: xHCI Host Controller
               vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic xhci-hcd
               physical id: 1
               bus info: usb@8
               logical name: usb8
               version: 4.04
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (NB-SB link)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:26 memory:fe400000-fe6fffff
       *-network
            description: Network controller
            product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Broadcom Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            version: 03
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
            resources: irq:36 memory:fe600000-fe607fff memory:fe400000-fe5fffff
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 11
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
         version: 40
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=32
         resources: irq:19 ioport:f040(size=8) ioport:f030(size=4) ioport:f020(size=8) ioport:f010(size=4) ioport:f000(size=16) memory:feb0b000-feb0b3ff
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 12
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:feb0a000-feb0afff
       *-usbhost
            product: OHCI PCI host controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@4
            logical name: usb4
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 12.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:17 memory:feb09000-feb090ff
       *-usbhost
            product: EHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@1
            logical name: usb1
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=480Mbit/s
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 13
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:feb08000-feb08fff
       *-usbhost
            product: OHCI PCI host controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@5
            logical name: usb5
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb:3
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 13.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:17 memory:feb07000-feb070ff
       *-usbhost
            product: EHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@2
            logical name: usb2
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=480Mbit/s
    *-serial
         description: SMBus
         product: SBx00 SMBus Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 42
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 14.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
         version: 40
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
         resources: irq:16 memory:feb00000-feb03fff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 14.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
         version: 40
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
    *-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 14.4
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.4
         version: 40
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master vga_palette
    *-usb:4
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 14.5
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.5
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:feb06000-feb06fff
       *-usbhost
            product: OHCI PCI host controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@6
            logical name: usb6
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-pci:4
         description: PCI bridge
         product: SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 15
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:fe800000-fe8fffff
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
            logical name: enp5s0
            version: 10
            serial: 40:8d:5c:ff:73:bd
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
            resources: irq:39 memory:fe800000-fe83ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
    *-pci:5
         description: PCI bridge
         product: SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 15.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16 memory:fe700000-fe7fffff
       *-usb
            description: USB controller
            product: VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller
            vendor: VIA Technologies, Inc.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
            version: 01
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
            resources: irq:35 memory:fe700000-fe700fff
          *-usbhost:0
               product: xHCI Host Controller
               vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic xhci-hcd
               physical id: 0
               bus info: usb@11
               logical name: usb11
               version: 4.04
               capabilities: usb-3.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
          *-usbhost:1
               product: xHCI Host Controller
               vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic xhci-hcd
               physical id: 1
               bus info: usb@10
               logical name: usb10
               version: 4.04
               capabilities: usb-2.00
               configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
             *-usb
                  description: USB hub
                  product: USB2.0 Hub
                  vendor: VIA Labs, Inc.
                  physical id: 1
                  bus info: usb@10:1
                  version: 4.20
                  capabilities: usb-2.10
                  configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
                *-usb:0
                     description: Keyboard
                     product: USB Receiver
                     vendor: Logitech
                     physical id: 1
                     bus info: usb@10:1.1
                     version: 12.03
                     capabilities: usb-2.00
                     configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
                *-usb:1
                     description: Generic USB device
                     product: 802.11 n WLAN
                     vendor: Ralink
                     physical id: 2
                     bus info: usb@10:1.2
                     version: 1.01
                     serial: 1.0
                     capabilities: usb-2.00
                     configuration: driver=rt2800usb maxpower=450mA speed=480Mbit/s
    *-usb:5
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: ohci bus_master
         configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:18 memory:feb05000-feb05fff
       *-usbhost
            product: OHCI PCI host controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@7
            logical name: usb7
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-1.10
            configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb:6
         description: USB controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
         physical id: 16.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.2
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
         resources: irq:17 memory:feb04000-feb040ff
       *-usbhost
            product: EHCI Host Controller
            vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
            physical id: 1
            bus info: usb@3
            logical name: usb3
            version: 4.04
            capabilities: usb-2.00
            configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
 *-pci:1
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h Processor Function 0
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 101
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:2
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h Processor Function 1
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 102
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:3
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h Processor Function 2
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 103
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:4
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h Processor Function 3
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 104
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=k10temp
      resources: irq:0
 *-pci:5
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h Processor Function 4
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 105
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=fam15h_power
      resources: irq:0
 *-pci:6
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 15h Processor Function 5
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 106
      bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-scsi
      physical id: 1
      logical name: scsi0
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: SanDisk SDSSDHP1
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 6RL
         serial: 142101415639
         size: 119GiB (128GB)
         capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
         configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=db70832a-5338-45bc-acbe-9691e6f5fce5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
       *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
            description: Windows FAT volume
            vendor: mkfs.fat
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
            version: FAT32
            serial: 4364-3855
            size: 510MiB
            capacity: 511MiB
            capabilities: boot fat initialized
            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI System Partition
       *-volume:1
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            logical name: /
            version: 1.0
            serial: c3f48954-3aa4-4608-92bb-53825d323276
            size: 110GiB
            capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2016-11-06 11:45:37 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2016-11-06 11:52:46 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2016-11-06 11:52:46 state=mounted
       *-volume:2
            description: Linux swap volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 3
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
            logical name: /dev/sda3
            version: 1
            serial: fbcc13d7-2d15-47d4-868a-70d72712f6b0
            size: 8152MiB
            capacity: 8153MiB
            capabilities: nofs swap initialized
            configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@10:1.2
   logical name: wlx60a44cec7115
   serial: 60:a4:4c:ec:71:15
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.4.0-45-generic firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.11.3 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

Comment: I'd recommend you post the full output of `sudo lshw` for detailed report of your hardware. Have you done any research? there seems to be many freeze cases around this `bcmwl`... e.g. you could suffer a bug like [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1415880)?

Comment: thanks for the response i edited my post with the output but i don't know how to edit it to make it more readable. Anyways how do i know i suffer from this type of bug? when it freezes it completing takes out the os and makes it unbootable so i just have been reinstalling to overcome that.Also how am i suppose to apply the patch if my system doesn't even have the bcmwl package already installed? The only research i have done is was mainly from here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers]

Comment: Could you please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run `sudo apt-get install -f bcmwl-kernel-source` and [edit] your question to include its output? If you can't capture the output because the system is frozen, could you maybe take a picture with a camera and link to it here? The most important thing are the last few lines before the system freezes. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the post to include a link to the photo. It freezes at this point every time, even in 16.10 and also in linux mint aswell.

Comment: Does it freeze or is the terminal just hanging there? How long did you wait?

Comment: Please do: `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` Detach the USB and try again: `sudo apt-get install -f bcmwl-kernel-source` Is the behavior the same?

Comment: it is completely frozen and even wont pull up a new terminal and I waited hours. I cant purge the system because when it freezes it completely ruins my build making it unbootable Also not sure what usb you mean? I tried it multiple times with and with our different devices plugged in still no go.